# An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request

Tags: javascript, html, .net, model-view-controller

how can i fix this error

An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
AmbiguousMatchException: The request matched multiple endpoints. Matches:

CoreDemo.Areas.Admin.Controllers.HomeController.Index (CoreDemo)
CoreDemo.Controllers.HomeController.Index (CoreDemo)

namespace CoreDemo.Controllers
{
public class HomeController : Controller
{
private readonly ILogger _logger;

```
    public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public IActionResult Privacy()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
    public IActionResult Error()
    {
        return View(new ErrorViewModel { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier });
    }
    public IActionResult Test()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

}

```
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

namespace CoreDemo.Areas.Admin.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you register to controllers with the same name (HomeController) without defining a custom Route then .net doesn't know which to pick.

You can give your controllers custom routes by using the Route attribute see docs here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-7.0#attribute-routing-with-http-verb-attributes

So you can add the Route attribute like this to your code:

```
namespace CoreDemo.Areas.Admin.Controllers
{
    [Route("admin/[controller]/[action]")]
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return ControllerContext.MyDisplayRouteInfo();
        }
    }
}

namespace CoreDemo.Controllers 
{ 
    [Route("[controller]/[action]")]
    public class HomeController : Controller 
    { 
        private readonly ILogger _logger;
    
        public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }
    
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
    
        public IActionResult Privacy()
        {
            return View();
        }
    
        [ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
        public IActionResult Error()
        {
            return View(new ErrorViewModel { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier });
        }
        public IActionResult Test()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are welcome. Please mark the answer as correct if you think it helped you.